# Como utilizar Methods de uma Classe Extends?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

> Possuo duas classes : **A e B**
>
> A Classe B está assim: **B extends A**
>
> Eu preciso utilizar alguns **methods** que **possui dentro da Class
>   A**,
>   **na da classe B**

.

**Como eu faço?**

```
class NeorisMapBi {
    constructor(mapID, mapOBJ){
        this._mapID = mapID;
        this._mapOBJ = mapOBJ;
    }

    get MapBi(){
        return this._mapOBJ;
    };
}

class CustomControl extends NeorisMapBi {
    constructor(divID, divCLASS, divPOSITION, buttonID, buttonCLASS, buttonTITLE, buttonINNERHTML){
        this._divID = divID;
        this._divCLASS = divCLASS;
        this._divPOSITION = divPOSITION;

        this._buttonID = buttonID;
        this._buttonCLASS = buttonCLASS;
        this._buttonTITLE = buttonTITLE;
        this._buttonINNERHTML = buttonINNERHTML;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `super.MapBi();` ?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), `super` é usada para acessar o objeto parente de um objeto.

Defina `getters` e `setters`.

```
...
set velocidade(km) {
    this.km = km;
}
get velocidade() {
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} esta se movimentando a ${this.km} KM/h!`);
}
...
```

Para utilizar, basta chamar normalmente.

```
// Set
gol.velocidade = 20;
// Get
gol.velocidade;
```

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
class Carro {
  constructor(modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.km = 0;
  }
  set velocidade(km) {
    this.km = km;
  }
  get velocidade() {
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} esta se movimentando a ${this.km} KM/h!`);
  }
  get movimentar() {
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} em movimento!`);
  }
  
  parar() {
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} parou!`);
  }
}

class Palio extends Carro {
  abastecer() {
    super.parar();
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} está abastecendo!`);
    super.movimentar;
  }
}

class Mobi extends Palio {
  // recebe como parâmetro: modelo, step
  constructor(modelo, step) {
    // Aqui, ele chama a classe construtora pai com o modelo
    super(modelo);
    this.step = step;
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} ${this.step}!`);
  }
  abastecer() {
    console.log(`Veículo ${this.modelo} está abastecendo!`);
  }
}

let gol = new Carro('Gol');
gol.movimentar;
gol.velocidade = 20;
gol.velocidade;
gol.parar();
gol.velocidade = 0;
gol.velocidade;

let palio = new Palio('Palio Fire');
palio.abastecer();

let mobi = new Mobi('Mobi Like', 'Não tem step');
mobi.movimentar;
mobi.parar();
mobi.abastecer();
mobi.movimentar;
```

Comment: Quando eu faço o uso do super  em no method get acima, ele me retorna undefiened.

Comment: @ThiagoDeBonisCarvalhoSaad, veja agora. Exemplifiquei o uso.

Comment: então na class que foi extendida eu não posso ter um construtor é isso?

Comment: Pode sim, vou editar.

Comment: ah acho que entendi.. Então o construct nessa classe extendida o "modelo" é o atributo da classe pai e o "step" é o atributo da classe filha?